Filtering IBM MQ Messages on a custom property using MuleSoft IBM MQ Connector
How can I filter messages from an IBM MQ based on a custom property or attribute using IBM MQ Mule connector?
The use case is that the back end system posts several messages on the Queue which may have the some sort of same ID as a property.
There is an API sitting in front of the Queue which is supposed to take an ID as the parameter and return all the messages that are present in the queue that have the same ID. Essentially read the messages from the queue on demand and return all the messages that have the same ID as requested by the API.
Note that the ID should be a custom property and not the CORRELATION_ID
Now the MQ connector has a selector input but that works on JMS filtering of messages based on correlation ID or JMS Priority etc.Can it be used to filter based on a custom property. What is the best way to implement something like this other?

Please try to make the question more focused on a single question.

What is it that you do not understand in the question ? I need to file IBM MQ records by a custom property. How can I do that ?

I am unable to understand the approach. Lets say first message is pushed to the queue with custom id "A", the consumer will process it. If there is a second message with id "A" the first message would have already been processed?

I need to get all the messages that have the ID A that are present on the Queue; concatenate them and send as a single response to the aPI back

Can you give more details on the use case as it seems like it is not a common pattern to be used with queues?. Do you want a system where you do not immediately process each message and aggregate messages of same IDs after certain interval (like collect all messages every 5 minute)? Or maybe when there are "n" number of messages (like of there are 10 messages with ID A then process it)?

Yes the requirement is to read the messages from the queue only on demand. So if the API requests for a specific ID then read all the messages from the queue with that ID and return to the API consumer. The messages has TTL as 30 minutes after which they are deleted from the queue.

You can set a custom message property and then set a selector based on that property when you consume messages,  the message property is part of the message header not the message body.
